# Recyclerview not showing any elements

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

As I said at the title, my recyclerview is not showing any elements inside of it. I want to make an app which a user can save the locations of where they visited.
I tried to create custom class for adapter and I did it. After that when user marks a location and saves it, it saves into my db. There is no problem with that but after adding the location I want to display it in my Recyclerview but it's not showing any elements.

**Main Activity**

```
package com.zecky_dev.travelbook_project;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int itemID = item.getItemId();
        switch(itemID){
            case R.id.addLocation_BTN:
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**LocationModel Class**

```
package com.zecky_dev.travelbook_project;

public class LocationModel {

    private String locationName;
    private double locationLatitude,locationLongitude;
    private int locationImage,locationID;
    public LocationModel(int locationID,String locationName,double locationLatitude,double locationLongitude,int locationImage)
    {
        this.locationID = locationID;
        this.locationName = locationName;
        this.locationLatitude = locationLatitude;
        this.locationLongitude = locationLongitude;
        this.locationImage = locationImage;
    }

    public String getLocationName() {
        return locationName;
    }

    public void setLocationName(String locationName) {
        this.locationName = locationName;
    }

    public double getLocationLatitude() {
        return locationLatitude;
    }

    public void setLocationLatitude(double locationLatitude) {
        this.locationLatitude = locationLatitude;
    }

    public double getLocationLongitude() {
        return locationLongitude;
    }

    public void setLocationLongitude(double locationLongitude) {
        this.locationLongitude = locationLongitude;
    }

    public int getLocationImage() {
        return locationImage;
    }

    public void setLocationImage(int locationImage) {
        this.locationImage = locationImage;
    }

    public int getLocationID() {
        return locationID;
    }

    public void setLocationID(int locationID) {
        this.locationID = locationID;
    }
}
```

**Maps Activity**

```
package com.zecky_dev.travelbook_project;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.zecky_dev.travelbook_project.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapsBinding binding;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    // Views
    private SearchView locationSearch_SW;
    private Button saveLocation_BTN;
    private EditText locationName_ET;

    // variables
    private final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 99;
    private double currentLatitude=0.0,currentLongitude=0.0;
    private double markedLocationLatitude=0.0,markedLocationLongitude=0.0;
    private String locationName_str;

    private ArrayList<LocationModel> locationModels;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    private RecyclerView locationList_RW;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.preview_map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationModels = new ArrayList<LocationModel>();
        locationList_RW = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.savedLocations_RW);

        //  Initialization of FusedProviderClient
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        // Location Search View Processes
        locationSearch_SW = findViewById(R.id.searchLocation_SW);
        locationSearch_SW.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        locationSearch_SW.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String queryString) {
                geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
                List<Address> addressList = null;
                String locationDescription = queryString;
                try{
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationDescription,1);
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                finally {
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    if(address.hasLatitude() && address.hasLongitude()){
                        double addressLat = address.getLatitude();
                        double addressLong = address.getLongitude();
                        LatLng searchedAddressLatLng = new LatLng(addressLat,addressLong);
                        Marker Custom = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(searchedAddressLatLng).title("Aradığınız nokta")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA))
                                .snippet(address.getAddressLine(0)));
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(searchedAddressLatLng,15));
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Database helper initialization
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MapsActivity.this);
        // Save location button initialization
        saveLocation_BTN = findViewById(R.id.saveLocation_BTN);
        locationName_ET = findViewById(R.id.locationName_ET);
        saveLocation_BTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                locationName_str = locationName_ET.getText().toString();
                if(!(locationName_str.isEmpty()) && (markedLocationLatitude!=0.0 && markedLocationLongitude!=0.0)){
                    if(dbHelper.addNewLocation(locationName_str,markedLocationLongitude,markedLocationLatitude)!=-1) {
                        cursor = dbHelper.readAllData();
                        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                            LocationModel location = new LocationModel
                                    (
                                            cursor.getInt(0),
                                            cursor.getString(1),
                                            cursor.getDouble(3),
                                            cursor.getDouble(2),
                                            cursor.getInt(4)
                                    );
                            locationModels.add(location);
                        }
                        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MapsActivity.this,locationModels);
                        locationList_RW.setAdapter(customAdapter);
                        locationList_RW.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "İşaretlenen lokasyon başarıyla veritabanına eklendi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Lütfen lokasyon ismi girin ve bir nokta işaretleyin..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        if(checkLocationPermission()){
            goCurrentLocation();
        }
        // Add marker to map where user long clicked and get it's position as clicked location
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
                markedLocationLatitude = latLng.latitude;
                markedLocationLongitude = latLng.longitude;
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions
                        .position(new LatLng(currentLatitude,currentLongitude))
                        .title("Bulunduğun konum")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                markerOptions
                        .position(latLng)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                        .title("İşaretlediğin konum");
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));
            }
        });
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    // Checking of location permissions
    public boolean checkLocationPermission()
    {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            // İzin verilmemiş
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
                AlertDialog.Builder permissionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                permissionDialog
                        .setTitle("İzin Gerekli!")
                        .setMessage("Uygulamanın konumunuza erişebilmesi için konum iznini vermeniz gerekiyor..")
                        .setPositiveButton("İzin ver", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                requestPermissions();
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            }
            else{
                requestPermissions();
            }
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Request location permissions if it's not given
    public void requestPermissions()
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                MapsActivity.this,
                new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                },PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch(requestCode){
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if(grantResults.length>0){
                    if(hasAllPermissionsGranted(grantResults)){
                        goCurrentLocation();
                    }
                }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    // Check if all permissions are granted or not
    public boolean hasAllPermissionsGranted(int[] grantResults)
    {
        for(int grantResult : grantResults){
            if(grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Go the current location through gps
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void goCurrentLocation()
    {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient
                .getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if(location!=null){
                            currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                            currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                            LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude,currentLongitude);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLatLng).title("Bulunduğun konum"));
                            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng,15));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**Custom Adapter Class**

```
package com.zecky_dev.travelbook_project;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<LocationModel> locationModels;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<LocationModel> locationModels){
        this.context = context;
        this.locationModels = locationModels;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_custom_layout,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.location_name_tw.setText(locationModels.get(position).getLocationName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return locationModels.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView location_name_tw;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            location_name_tw = itemView.findViewById(R.id.savedLocationName_TW);
        }
    }
}
```

**Database Helper Class**

```
package com.zecky_dev.travelbook_project;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "LocationDB";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "locations";
    private static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_NAME = "location_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_LATITUDE = "location_latitude";
    private static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_LONGITUDE = "location_longitude";
    private static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_IMAGE = "location_image";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + COLUMN_LOCATION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + COLUMN_LOCATION_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_LOCATION_LONGITUDE + " REAL,"
                + COLUMN_LOCATION_LATITUDE + " REAL,"
                + COLUMN_LOCATION_IMAGE + " BLOB)";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public long addNewLocation(String locationName,Double locationLongitude,double locationLatitude)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_LOCATION_NAME,locationName);
        values.put(COLUMN_LOCATION_LATITUDE,locationLatitude);
        values.put(COLUMN_LOCATION_LONGITUDE,locationLongitude);
        long isInserted = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        return isInserted;
    }

    public boolean deleteLocation(int locationID)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_LOCATION_ID + "=" + locationID,null) > 0;
    }

    public void updateLocation(int locationID,String newLocationName){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LOCATION_NAME,newLocationName);
        sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,COLUMN_LOCATION_ID + " = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(locationID)});
    }
    public void updateLocation(int locationID,String newLocationName,double newLocationLongitude,double newLocationLatitude){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LOCATION_NAME,newLocationName);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LOCATION_LATITUDE,newLocationLatitude);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_LOCATION_LONGITUDE,newLocationLongitude);
        sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,COLUMN_LOCATION_ID + " = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(locationID)});
    }

    public Cursor readAllData()
    {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        if(sqLiteDatabase!=null){
            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

[Activity Main Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH46O.png)
[Activity Maps Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhjIx.jpg)

**Activity Main XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:text="@string/saved_locations_TW"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/savedLocations_RW"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity Maps XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/preview_map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/locationName_ET"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchLocation_SW"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/locationName_ET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="596dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/location_name_hint_ET"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveLocation_BTN"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
        android:text="@string/save_location_btn_text"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.533"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locationName_ET"
        map:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.428" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchLocation_SW"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryBackground="@null"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: your MainActivity doesn't contains any code to show RecyclerView

Comment: I added it to Maps Activity because it wasn't updating instantly when user add new location it was only updating when user close the app

Comment: perhaps i'm misunderstanding, but your recyclerview is inside `Activity Main XML` but all the code for it is inside `Maps Activity` ?

Comment: can you explain purpose of dbHelper.addNewLocation(locationName_str,markedLocationLongitude,markedLocationLatitude)!=-1, coz wondering maybe your 'if' isn't executing?

Comment: I was wanting update the recylerview instantly when user add new location but it was doing it only when user close app and restart, to prevent it I add it to MapsActivity with this way when user click save location button program can see click activity and update it.

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah markedLocationLongitude and latitude value changes when user long click to mapp and it adds a marker to this location and takes the longitude and latitude value of it. By default these values are 0.0. As I said at the subject it adds the location to db successfully but it's not showing. Also,dbHelper.addNewLocation adds new row to db.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I solved it by adding code to Main Activity but now when user add a location from Maps Activity it doesn't update the recyclerview until user close and start application.